# How much does Medicare pay an insurance company to assume a Medicare Advantage policy's risk?

Tags: medicare

If you sign up for a Medicare Advantage plan, you continue to pay the Medicare Part B premium ($177.10 in 2022). [Medicare then pays a fixed amount for your care each month to the companies offering Medicare Advantage Plans](https://www.medicare.gov/sign-upchange-plans/types-of-medicare-health-plans/medicare-advantage-plans/how-do-medicare-advantage-plans-work) in order to assume your risk. How much is that amount?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're asking, or you're just curious? I'm sure you can get the details of the specific contracts through a FOIA request

Comment: I'm signing up for Plan G but I'm trying to understand Medicare Advantage thoroughly because I'm trying to get one of my brothers off of Kaiser during the first year when he can easily switch back.

Comment: If it's still offered, you should evaluate a high deductible supplement.  I think that the deductible is $2,490 a year and you pay the 20% until you meet it.  For me, the worst case scenario will still cost me less than paying much more up front in order to have a zero copay.  And if your annual health care costs are low, you'll save a substantial amount of money.

Comment: There is a Plan K which is kind of a high deductible. However, it doesn't cover Excess Charges or foreign travel.

Comment: @Olsonist - that's not what I'm referring to.  If you go for the G supplement, you have the alternative of going with the high deductible G.  The plans are identical except that the premium and deductibles are different. I chose the F plan.  I had the choice of $325 a month ($3,900 a year) with no copay or $64 a month ($768) with a $2,490 deductible (was less when I started).  For example, if I have $500 in copays this year, I'm out $1,268 instead of $3,900.  If it hits the fan and I hit the max, I'm out $3,258 ($768 + $2,490) which is still less than $3,900.  The HD plan is a no brainer.

Comment: Continued: [Read this](https://www.medigap.com/medicare-supplements/high-deductible-plan-g/)

Comment: Yes, there is a High Deductible G available in my zip for between $35-$66. The downsides of these plans are you're stuck on HDG and there aren't any Community Priced plans. Regular G is $123 from UHC/AARP. So the gamble is (123-35)*12 = $1056. However, you blow through that saving in a bad year. My brother is taking advantage of the Medicare trial period doing free Advantage for a year then switching to K. That year will save him $2400 (in WA). But myself, I just don't want to ever think about copays as a reason not to see the doctor. Different finances. Mostly I just hate Medicare Advantage.

Comment: If Regular G only costs you $123 a month then that's the better choice.  $123 seems very low so I'd doublecheck that.